# Как ограничить доступ к файлу

Tags: java, файловая-система

Добрый день. Потратил полтора дня на то, чтобы найти способ создать файл так, чтобы к нему не имел доступа пользователь ну или имел, но разобрать что в нём написано не мог. К сожалению я ничего не нашёл. Надёжное шифрование файла с помощью ключа возможно, только если ключ всё время запрашивать у пользователя и не сохранять его вообще. Всё остальное вполне возможно обойти. Решил попробовать просто ограничить доступ к файлу. Возьмём винду с 2 учётными записями. Мы запускаем приложение с одной из них, в итоге в этой записи в домашнем каталоге будет создаваться этот файл. Я хотел ограничить доступ к файлу всем, кроме того, с чей учётной записи этот файл был создан. Но и тут меня ожидал провал. Я пробовал что-то вроде такого

```
File file = new File(path);
Files.setOwner(file.toPath(), () -> System.getProperty("user.name"));
System.out.println(file.setReadable(false));
```

Этот код должен делать то, что я описал выше, но во первых на строке 2 исключительная ситуация, причину которой я вообще не понимаю, а на строке 3 как результат должно вернуть true, а возвращает false на windows, а на linux работает всё ок... Такие дела. В общем я в тупике и нужен вариант ограничения доступа к файлу. Ну или если у вас есть есть другая идея для решения данной проблемы тоже попрошу поделиться, но файл должен хранится локально.

Comment: java как бы задумывалась как мультиплатформенное решение. И врдя ли в ней получится сделать что-то специфическое для определенной операционное системы. Поэтому лучше все же подумать в сторону шифрования.

Comment: @newman ну любое шифрование является по сути своей алгоритмом, в лучшем случае алгоритмом с входными данными. Любой код можно декомпилировать, скопировать код, который дешифрует зашифрованный файл в отдельную прогу, запустить её и просмотреть всё содержимое файла. Таким образом лучшим способом шифрования, а ещё лучше просто использовать этот ключ как пароль к бд, является постоянный запрос ключа у пользователя при старте приложения, а это рано или поздно очень надоедает.

Comment: Никто не мешает использовать для шифрования, например элетронную подпись, которая находится на токене, который вставлен в USB порт. И у пользовтаеля ничего не надо спрашивать. Тут другой вопрос - насколько это надо. Зависит от кого защищаться надо. Как показывает опыт в 99% случаев, чтобы что-то скрыть от пользователя достаточнj обычного XOR по ключу в десяток символов.

Comment: @newman ну так опять таки, просто декомпилируем код и видим, что шифруется через usb токен, сами узнаём его и используем для расшифровки. Ну для обычного пользователя я бы даже и в коде сразу оставил ключ к бд и не парился)

Comment: Делать удаленную проверку на сайте запросом ключа пользователя + кроем аплюкуху стрингером

Comment: @GenCloud я не хочу при каждом входе в приложение напрягать пользователя вводом ключа, ну а если и напрягать, то всё можно свести к обычному алгоритму дешифровки с этим ключом. Если ключ верный вернёт осмысленный пароль к бд, а если нет, то вернёт мусор и неверный пароль к бд, и тогда приложение вырубится